# C# KeyValuePair<string, int> List - to <string> without preserving the int value

Tags: c#, list, key-value

My initialization is:

```
List<string> convertedList = new List<string>();  
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> originalList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```

And I basically want to populate `convertedList` with *only* the string values in `originalList`
So if `originalList` has some items: `["foo",5],["bar",16],["baz",100]`,
 I want `convertedList` to contain: `["foo"],["bar"],["baz"]`
So far I've tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= originalList.Count; i++)
{
    convertedList.Add(actions.ToString());
}
```

but with no luck.
Oh, and keep in mind that I'm a newbie and the answers to this might be really obvious.
Thanks for helping me out!
**And how would I go about proceeding if I want to convert only the first X items?**

Comment: use Take(N). Eg: convertedList.AddRange(originalList.Take(7).Select(x => x.Key)) and do not rely on it that something called your question again, just in case I've seen it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 List<String> convertedList = originalList.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Or:

```
  convertedList.AddRange(originalList.Select(x => x.Key));
```

Comment: If you want to append instead of of making a new list use can use `convertedList.AddRange(originalList.Select(kvp => kvp.Key));`

Comment: @Scott, We changed our answers apparently exactly the same second :-)
correct comment.

Comment: You don't need the `ToList()` in the `AddRange` version as AddRange takes in a `IEnumerable<T>` which is exactly what `Select` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to the original syntax:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in originalList)
{
    convertedList.Add(kvp.Key);
}
```